# Compute columns, are there any better ways than my subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I am having some trouble trying to compute a column

DF1

```
Date         transaction_number  tender_amt   tender_type
2017-01-01   001                 20           euros
2017-01-01   001                 10           american
2017-01-01   002                 20           american
2017-01-02   001                 40           american
2017-01-01   003                 40           euros
2017-01-01   004                 50           american
```

How can I create a computed column that divides the tender_amt from euro/american based on the transaction number and date?

DF-Desired

```
Date         transaction_number  tender_amt   tender_type     exchange_rate(euro/american)  
2017-01-01   001                 20           euros            2              
2017-01-01   001                 10           american         2
2017-01-01   002                 20           american         (null)       
2017-01-02   001                 40           american         (null)
2017-01-01   003                 40           euros            (null)
2017-01-01   004                 50           american         (null)
```

my attempt

```
Select Date, transaction_number, tender_amt, tender_type, 
exchange_rate = (Select O.tender_amt / B.tender_amt as exchange_rate
From df1 O
Inner Join df1 as B on B.Date = O.Date and B.transaction_number = O.transaction_number
where  O.transaction_number = a.transaction_number 
and O.Date = a.Date and O.tender_type = 'euro' and B.tender_type = 'american'
)
from df1 a
```

Are there any better ways?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are really using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me assume SQL Server.  You can use window functions:

```
select df1.*,
       (max(case when tender_type = 'euros' then tender_amt end) over (partition by Date, transaction_number) /
        max(case when tender_type = 'american' then tender_amt end) over (partition by Date, transaction_number)
       ) as exchange_rate       
from df1;
```